# Not understanding this notation

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, numerical-linear-algebra

What is the magnitude (length) of vector µv for the following µ?
a) µ = 0 b) µ = length of v c) µ = 1/length of v µ = 1/length of v squared

What is µv? what is  µ?

Comment: $\mu v$ could denote multiplying vector $v$ by scalar $\mu$

Comment: That is what I thought but how do I do that with the information provided? This is the complete question.

Comment: note that $\mid \mu v\mid=\mid \mu\mid \mid v \mid$

Answer (score 0):

Let $||v||$ represent the length/norm of a vector $v$. $\mu$ is a scalar, and $\mu v$ is the vector multiplied by the scalar. Generally, we have that $$||\mu v||=|\mu|\cdot||v||$$

So, the question is asking you what $||\mu v||$ is when:
$$a) \ \mu= 0$$
$$b) \ \mu=||v||$$
$$c) \ \mu=\frac{1}{||v||}$$
$$d) \ \mu=\frac{1}{||v||^2}$$